# C++ rounding to 1 decimal, displaying 2 decimals

Tags: c++, rounding

Maybe I didn't understand it in different context or didn't find it, but I just needed to know how to round a double to 1 decimal place but display 2 decimals

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(1);
```

rounds it, but how would I go about displaying the extra zero after an answer.

ex. displaying 1.50 instead of 1.5

Is there a way to do this without including math?

**EDIT:**

I guess what I'm asking is: Is there a way to setprecision(2) while rounding to the first decimal?

Currently when I set it to setprecision(2) I get 1.49 and I would just like to keep the trailing zero rather than using setprecision(1)

Sorry for the poorly explained question.

Comment: Assuming that the value is not exactly `1.50` (or could be rounded to exactly that value, using e.g. `setprecision(2)`) then I would argue that your program would be lying to the user. *Why* do you want to lie to the user? *Why* do you want to do this? What is the *actual* problem you attempt to solve by doing this? You might want to read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and think about how your question relates to that. And of course [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you could actually round the number before printing it, `cout` can't do everything

Comment: `cout` and its maniputlators dont round the value of the variable, but they just control what you see on the screen. You need to first round the value and then display it

Comment: `cout << setprecision(1) << fixed << 1.491 << '0';`

Comment: There is a use case for currency when you want to round to 10 cent.  They already did that in the Netherlands (I forgot whether it was 5 or 10 cents).  I guess it would still be misleading if it was not clear that that was the intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention you don't want to *include math* (but don't say exactly why). Based on this, you can use a cast to int to do the rounding instead:

```
const double x = 1.51;
const double rounded_x = static_cast<int>(x * 10) / 10.0;
cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << rounded_x;
```

**Update**

If you want to round to the nearest value (1.49 -> 1.5, instead of 1.4), just:

```
const double rounded_x = static_cast<int>(x * 10 + 0.5) / 10.0;
```

Finally, you don't tell anything about negative numbers, above code will round -1.49 to -1.4. If you want to round to -1.5, then use following instead:

```
const double rounded_x = static_cast<int>(x * 10 + (x >= 0.0 ? 0.5 : -0.5)) / 10.0;
```

---

Of course, you can always do something like:

```
const double x = 1.51;
cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << x << '0';
```

but I have the feeling that it is not the type of hack you are looking for ;)

Comment: Consider using [std::round](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) instead of adding 0.5 and casting.

Comment: @Bob__ yes but the OP wanted an answer _without including math_ ;)

Comment: Fair enough ;). It's still not clear what is OP's use case, if it's currency, floating point math may not be the best choice anyway.

Comment: If it's unavoidable that's alright, I just didn't want to include extra stuff since it's an assignment, although a poorly explained one, which makes asking questions quite difficult. Thanks for your help.